# How to load Spring's application context with a Fitnesse test fixture?

Tags: java, spring, automated-tests, fitnesse

I have this test fixture I want to run with Fitnesse and it involves using Spring. I haven't been able to load the spring application context with the ClasspathXmlApplicationContext, and I'm sure is a classpath configuration thing that I just haven't figured it out.

So here's my setup.

[image: Project contents]

As you can see, the fitnesse.jar is inside the project, so I can run the fitnesse server  and the tests anywhere I have a working copy of the project (all the wiki files are inside the FitNesseRoot folder). The **bin** is the output folder of the project (where all the .class are).

Now, the code:

**InventarioQueryTest** (wiki page from Fitnesse, notice the **!path** declarations)

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

!path ../bin
!path ../web/WEB-INF/lib/**.jar

|import                                |
|com.softclear.inventario.test.fitnesse|


|Query:listar status          |
|id|nombre|entidad|descripcion|
```

**ListarStatus.java** (the text fixture invoked by Fitnesse)

```
public class ListarStatus {

    private ServicioStatus serv;
    private ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx;

    //fitnesse calls the constructor
    public ListarStatus(){
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {
                "applicationContext-ListarStatus.xml",
                "applicationContext-dao.xml",
                "applicationContext-hibernate.xml"});

            //performs dependency injection of DAO and HibernateSession
        serv = (ServicioStatus) ctx.getBean("servicioStatus");
    }

    //and the query method is the test
    public List<Object> query() {
        List<Status> lista = serv.listarStatus();
        QueryResultBuilder builder = new QueryResultBuilder(Status.class);
        QueryResult result = builder.build(lista.iterator());
        return result.render();
    }
}
```

I run fitnesse with java -jar from the working copy of my project. And when I run the test, this is the command that fitnesse executes:

```
java -cp fitnesse.jar;../bin;C:\Dev\WS\softclear\SistemaInventario\fitnesse\..\web\WEB-INF\lib\ajax\AjaxFileUpload-0.03.jar;%the.rest.of.the.web-inf/lib.jars...%  fitnesse.slim.SlimService 8086
```

And all that produces this error in the test:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext-ListarStatus.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

As fas as I understand, the **!path ../bin** in the wiki should indicate all the subfolders and stuff to be included in the classpath (the java -cp call), but apparently it doesn't...

Any ideas? Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I resolved it, by doing this in the ListarStatus class:

```
public ListarStatus() {
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {
                "/com/softclear/inventario/test/fitnesse/applicationContext-ListarStatus.xml",
                "applicationContext-dao.xml",
                "applicationContext-hibernate.xml"});

        serv = (ServicioStatus) ctx.getBean("servicioStatus");
    }
```

Notice that the applicationContext-ListarStatus.xml file has a relative path and not just the name of the file.

Turns out that ClassPathXmlApplicationContext **DOES NOT** search *anywhere* in the classpath like I understood (read this, the part of the ClassPathXML...: http://freejavaclass.com/articles/j2ee/spring/spring_loading_types_ways.jsp). **At least not in Spring 2**.

It had nothing to do with Fitnesse, it was all Spring...